# Backbone.js - Filtering Collections versus multiple Collections

Tags: javascript, collections, filter, backbone.js

I'm building a filemanager using backbone.js. Its part of a CMS (content managament system) Im building, and is accessed via a lightbox/modal window. I need to show both files attached to a certain content type (like a post) and also all files in general.

At this point I have two separate collections, a libraryCollection (all files) and galleryCollection (a posts files). The first problem I've encountered with this method is: editing a file in the libraryCollection and binding a model change event to the view obviously doesnt affect the galleryCollection view.

Is there a better way to do this? Im thinking I will need pagination for the libraryCollection (as in REAL pagination with only xx number of results retrieved from the server) and this might complicate things. Unless loading potentially thousands of records into the collection is ok?

**Update:**

The quickest (possibly dirtiest) method was to use the built in Backbone.Events system. Sample code:

```
var aggregator = {};
_.extend(aggregator, Backbone.Events);

aggregator.on("fileUpdated", function(model){
    if(app.libraryCollection && app.galleryCollection){
        libraryModel = app.libraryCollection.get(model.get("id"));
        galleryModel = app.galleryCollection.get(model.get("id"));
        libraryModel.set(model.attributes);
        galleryModel.set(model.attributes);
    }   
});
```

Then the Editor view:

```
window.EditorView = Backbone.View.extend({

    saveModel: function(){
        self = this;
        form = $(this.el).find("form").serializeArray();
        _.each(form, function(field){
            self.model.set(field["name"], field["value"]);
        });
        self.model.save();
        aggregator.trigger("fileUpdated", this.model);
    }
});
```

This syncs the models across both collections, and because I bound the model change event with the render function (not shown) the view reflects the changes across both the library and gallery views.

Comment: I've had success building off of [sled's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6865316/45433) to the problem of a "master" collection and a secondary "subset" collection. See a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214712/implementing-backbone-subset-js-in-backbone-js-to-filter-models-from-a-parent-co

Comment: That looks like a more scalable solution. I will look into it more when I have time. Thanks

Comment: From your update: that's gross. At the very least that anonymous fn on fileUpdated should be a method on the galleryCollection view, bound *by* the galleryCollection view, not just floating in the global scope like that.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. I dont have separate galleryCollection and libraryCollection views. They both use ListView which iterates through the passed collection and renders a new ListItemView with the model. Complete code is here: http://pastebin.com/QvD5Pij3 I'm new to javascript in general and just followed the structure used on backbone's website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential solution to your problem of communicating between separate Backbone.js components is to us an event aggregator. In the event aggregator pattern, components such as views will share a reference to an aggregator, which is an object that serves as a central communications hub for your application. Instead of a view subscribing to events on another view, both talk to the aggregator, which passes messages along to any component that subscribes for that type of message.

For example, your `libraryCollection` might fire a `fileAdded` event on the aggregator, passing the new `file` object in the message. Your `galleryCollection` would subscribe to the `fileAdded` event on the aggregator, and it would take some action when it fires, such as refreshing itself from the server or adding the passed `file` object to itself.

Here's an [excellent blog post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/) that covers the event aggregator pattern.

Loading thousands of records into a collection at once sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Always glad to see more articles on Backbone. I never even noticed the Backbone.js Events module. I will definitely use it in the future. Thanks